# Rounded images - is it better to crop them rounded or use css?

Tags: css, image, performance

Assuming you have a ton of images to display(20+) on a page, is it better to use a set of pngs with transparent backgrounds causing a rounded image effect or to use jpgs and round the images using css?

I'm trying to significantly increase performance for a client site. Purely speaking from a user-performance aspect, which of the following options are likely to provide better results.

Option 1 - 
  Image format: png with transparent edges making images look like circles.

Option 2 - 
  Image format: jpg
  Images rounded to appear as circles using the border-radius css property.

Feel free to provide insight. It helps to understand this when asked in the future.

Comment: I feel this is going to get tagged for being a localized question, too specific to the OP's situation. Please find a way to reword my question, if that is the case. A lot of people I know have ran into this question but could not find answers. I kinda feel this is an important question. css vs image optimization. Id like a general answer.

Comment: Well one involves the rendering of an image, the other involves the rendering of an image and the browser doing a lot of work to crop it into a circle. Which would you think is more efficient?

Comment: @leigero Ah, but it's slightly more involved. While the cropped png will be more efficient to render, the jpg file would be smaller, therefore be more efficient to load.

Comment: @MrLister I suppose, but you'd have to really care about microseconds, or be loading a LOT of images for this to ever matter.

Comment: @AaronLoften If this is for an existing website that you want to increase the performance of, I'd say you can easily experiment, then go with what works best.

Comment: @leigero Rendering an alpha chanel also involves a lot of work ... It isn't clear at all wich one is more CPU intensive.

Answer (score 1):

This depends entirely on what you are refering to as "performance".

If you are talking about download speed: This depends on the type and size of your images. Usually bigger photographs with a lot of detail end up better as jpgs, graphics, images with sharp edges and smaller stuff are better as pngs.

If you are talking about rendering performance: Given your images had same size, regardless of type, using border-radii is of course slower when rendering, but with modern browsers, this should not really be a big deal.

I think the biggest factor is choosing the right image format for your use case and then deciding whether it is worth it having a person prepare all the images with transparent pixels instead of just letting the browser do the work.

I would suggest there are other areas on the page that could improve performance in a more significant way (etc. performant javascript, lazyloading of images, efficient markup (minimizing your code,choosing proper compression,...)).